# Misplaced else error in a loop to print prime numbers

Tags: c++, loops

In a program for printing prime numbers I keep getting an error of misplaced else and warning for unreachable value/address.

Code:

```
/*Q37-WAP to print prime numbers in a range*/
#include<iostream.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
   clrscr();
   int a,b,c,i,j;
   cout<<"Enter the smallest number:";
   cin>>a;
   cout<<"\nEnter the biggest number:";
   cin>>b;
   for(i=a;i<=b;i++)
   {
       for(int j=2;j<=i/2;j++)
       {
           if(i%j==0);
           {
                break;
           }
           else
           {
                cout<<i<<"\n";
           }
       }
   }
   getch();
}
```

Comment: Remove the `;` after the `if(i%j==0);`line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(i%j==0);
```

Removing the semicolon at the end of this line should make it work.

Comment: Nice you spotted that obvious error. The question is doomed anyways. Don't be disappointed loosing the rep, when it's killed.

Comment: @RaviSharmaRs: as well as not rushing people with "asap" and "urgent" devices, please also consider not using txtspk. Stack Overflow is not a chatroom.

Comment: @RaviSharmaRs Please stop that horrible leet speech when posting here, that's no way _professional_. And learn how to ping correctly also We're not your personal help-desk, or online debugging service. Your question simply is off-topic in it's current form, and should be deleted, because of zero value for future researchers.